# How to make select command work on button using Python in Maya?

Tags: python, select, command, maya

I’m new to Python programming and need help in Maya.

So I’m trying to create a UI with a button that selects an object named `"big"` in my maya scene, but I cannot get this to work. How do I add select command to my button `ball_btn`?

I have tried to plug `cmds.select("ball")` to the button but no luck.

Thank you!

```
ball_btn = mc.button(label = “”, w = 50, h = 30, bgc = [1.000,0.594,0.064])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maya docs already give you a good example on how to hook up a [button to a function](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/button.html).

Once your button triggers a function when it's clicked, you can do a simple check if the object exists in the scene and then select it:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


# Define a function that the button will call when clicked.
def select_obj(*args):
  if cmds.objExists("ball"):  # Check if there's an object in the scene called ball.
      cmds.select("ball")  # If it does exist, then select it.
  else:
      cmds.error("Unable to find ball in the scene!")  # Otherwise display an error that it's missing.


# Create simple interface.
win = cmds.window(width=150)
cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
cmds.button(label="Select", command=select_obj)  # Use command parameter to connect it to the earlier function.
cmds.showWindow(win)
```

You can also connect the button's command directly to `cmds.select` using `lambda`:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


# Create simple interface.
win = cmds.window(width=150)
cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
cmds.button(label="Select", command=lambda x: cmds.select("ball"))  # Use lambda to connect directly to the select method.
cmds.showWindow(win)
```

But then you would have zero customization with how it handles errors, or if you want it to do other things. Generally stick with the button triggering a function unless you have a good reason not to. Keep in mind you can use `lambda` for your own custom function too.

Comment: Thanks Green cell,Just perfect answer. I was getting wrong because I was plug in select command directly without defining a function for the button to call on.Thanks again!

Comment: You can also plug it directly in the select command, though I wouldn't suggest it. I updated the answer to give an example on how to do that.